# how to select select2 using another select2 values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have two select2 input boxes, My requirement is if I selected one select2 box that value will effect with another select2 box.

my code is as below:

```
<input class="select2-offscreen itemid_0" type="text" name="itemid" id="itemid[]" style="width:100px; left:297.5px !important; top:863px !important; float:left !important" tabindex="-1" onchange="display();">

<input class="select2-offscreen unitId_0" type="text" name="unitId" id="unitId[]" style="width:100px; left:297.5px !important; top:863px !important; float:left !important" tabindex="-1">


<script>
 function display(){
$(".unitId_0").select2("val","hr");
}
</script>
```

please tell me where I did mistake?

Thanks,
Madhuri

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?what do u mean by effect with?

Comment: i need to display value in select2 units

Comment: you can check my updated answer below,

Answer (score 1):

You mean the value in both boxes should be same, right?

```
$(function () {
    $(".itemid_0").keyup(function () { // on key up in first box
        var value = $(this).val();     // get its value
        $(".unitId_0").val(value);     // set the value of the second box to it
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/wL3PD/)

Answer (score 0):

Is it this you are looking for?

```
 $('.unitId_0').val("hr");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like,it should work.

```
var a=$(".itemid_0").val();
$('.unitId_0').val(a);
```

you can use `keyup` or `onclick` events